# My blog is on both blogspot.com and blogspot.co.id, how do I put it only on .com and get Google to recognize that?

Tags: seo, top-level-domains, blogger

When I search my blog on Google, I found that there are 2 blog URL, `http://xxx.blogspot.co.id` (doesn't have description) and `http://xxx.blogspot.com` (has description). How to make my blog URL only appear one using *.com* and has description?

How do I make my page appear with *.com* on Google?

Would it affect my SEO if my blog URL did use *.co.id*?

Comment: Google does this - serving different TLDs for different countries. [https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/2402711?hl=en] (Read This). Its OK. Doesn't affect any SEO.

Comment: My first and second question are not answered yet. Please help!

Comment: If you use custom domain name, it will not show ccTLDs. This Google support link would be very helpful. https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/2402711?hl=en